# OCMockito: how do you express "any CGRect" when verifying a function call parameter?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmockito

Let's say that I have a method like this

`[SomeObject someMethod:(id)object someRect:(CGRect)rect];`

When doing unit test, I want to very that this function is called with a specific object and any rect, but this code doesn't work:

```
[verifyCount(mockObject, MKTTimes(1)) someMethod:HC_equalTo(message) someRect:HC_anything()];
```

Compiler would say that HC_anything is not a CGRect.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: CGRect is not an object but a struct. I recommend that you just pass in random rects.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[verify(mockObject) withMatcher:anything() forArgument:1]
    someMethod:message someRect:CGRectZero];
```

Basically, pass in a rect that will be ignored, because we've overridden the matching using `withMatcher:forArgument:`

…Note that `verify` is short for `verifyCount` with `times(1)`. Also, passing `message` directly is short for `equalTo(message)`.